# AWS VPC Flow Logs Not Working with s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I have an S3 bucket that has SSE-KMS setup and is working properly.

When I attempt to enforce SSE via put requests as shown in the below link, VPC flow logs stop sending to the S3 bucket.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html

Any suggestions on next steps?
I also am unsure of where i could even see access denied, etc logs to start troubleshooting.

Comment: I did notice when i go to the flow logs tab on the VPC i see this error:
"log destination is not accessible."

It is fine until i enforce that encryption header

Comment: Have you [provided correct key policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs-s3.html#flow-logs-s3-cmk-policy) for your CMK in KMS to allow flow logs to use it?

Comment: is this ok instead of directly specifying "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
```
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
    },
```

Comment: technically yes, but its not a good practice. it means that any principle can use your cmk.

Comment: I see. Yah i'll definitely change that in the morning. Any other thoughts on what to try?

Comment: The bucket policy is for external users to upload with encryption. I'm not sure if you can enforce the same for internal AWS services. Have never seen that done for internal aws services. I think you can trust VPC FLs to use the default KMS encryption set on the bucket level, rather then try to circumvent it.

Comment: That makes sense. I can add a condition to skip the flow logs then maybe.